# How to make myBinder.org launch directly into Appmode

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, android-binder

I've made a simple app in jupyter notebook and I'm trying to make a shareable link directly into the app using mybinder.org.

However, my link takes the user to the notebook and then the user has to manually press the appmode button at the top to switch to appmode. I have seen examples of binders that directly take the user into the Appmode instead of the notebook. How can I make mine do the same?

Example of link that takes you directly to app:

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/oschuett/appmode/master?urlpath=%2Fapps%2Fexample_app.ipynb

My link:

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fahimnis/Practice-Project.git/master

I have tried editing my environment.yml file but I cannot get it to do what I want. My environment. yml file is

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python 3.7
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - appmode
```

This is the repository that produced the app above:

https://github.com/oschuett/appmode

My repository:

https://github.com/fahimnis/Practice-Project

Answer (score 2):

Once you have entered the repository URL, Git branch and Path to the notebook, do this:

1. In the Last Option which says:
   "Copy the text below, then paste into your README to show a binder badge", copy the first link.
2. It will look like this: (https://mybinder.org/badge_logo.svg)(https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/username/repository/master?filepath=Analysis.ipynb)
3. In "https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/username/repository/master?filepath=Analysis.ipynb", replace "?filepath=" with "?urlpath=apps%2F".

This is the Link to the web app version of the Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You append both `apps`  and the specific notebook to open onto the typical URL that you point users at for launching a session with your repo via MyBinder. It describes how to do it under ‘Decscription’ section at https://github.com/oschuett/appmode#description . An example is in the URL of the `launch binder` button at https://github.com/oschuett/appmode.

In your case the link is as follows

```
https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fahimnis/RelPermApp/master?urlpath=%2Fapps%2FRelPermApp.ipynb
```

Note how the typical launch URL of `https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fahimnis/Practice-Project/master` has been appended with the two items.