# How to mark a jupyter lab document as trusted when building through mybinder.org so that all codecells are run automaticaly

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I need all codecells in a jupyter lab document to run when opening it in binder. I've tried adding `jupyter trust <filename>` to the postbuild file but it does'nt work. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that it doesn’t work, does it at least show as trusted when you open the notebook? Because that approach is/was recommended way to set to trusted. Until the extension enabling example notebook was streamlined to only include an example that works in both the classic an JupyterLab interface, that was the way documented [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-extension/blob/00c9a3ae01ef7e7e77ce986b0561149de69b7d66/postBuild). [Here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html) discusses how to check if trusted.
However, just setting `trusted` does not trigger the code to run when the notebook is launched.
Aside of coding extension that will run code like `python-markdown`, there is no simple way to trigger that in the Binderhub system at this time. When this question came up the other day in the binder gitter channel, I suggested a person could most likely make an empty notebook appear to have just been run by using a `start` config file to trigger execution of the notebook via nbconvert or papermill.
Alternatively, using Appmode as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151628/how-to-make-mybinder-org-launch-directly-into-appmode) will execute all cells when run in app mode; however, the interface won’t be a notebook. Similarly, installing Voila and linking to the Voila render will run code in a notebook at launch. It will look like a web app interface and not a notebook though.

Comment: No it does not show as trusted when i open the notebook. However I have several codefiles that is run through a main file. I just realized I've only set the main file as trusted so maybe that could be part of the problem? Still it should at least be marked as trusted.

Comment: The main file should show as `trusted` if all is well. You would need to trust each. Is your postBuild actually executing? It has to show as executable and cannot be edited via GitHub’s browser interface. It breaks if you use that. You have to push a good one from local. Best to copy or clone a repo with a working one.